# Добавить элемент только 1 раз

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, при нажатии на кнопку редактировать создаю новую кнопку отмена, но эта кнопка отмены содается каждый раз при нажатии на редактировать, как этого избежать, чтоб кнопка отмены создавалась только раз
Кнопка редактирования

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn_edit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('data-url');

        if(url == 'UPDEducation') {
            $('button#education').attr('data-url', 'UPDEducation');
            $('button#education').text('<?=$text_save?>');

            $('<button/>', {
                text: '',
                id: 'clear_fields_education',
                class: 'clear_fields btn btn-default get pull-right'
            }).appendTo('#education fieldset legend');

            $('input#id_education').val($(this).attr('data'));
            $('input#date_of_the_beginning').val($('#'+$(this).attr('data')+' #td_date_of_the_beginning').text());
            $('input#end_date').val($('#'+$(this).attr('data')+' #td_end_date').text());
            $('input#education_received').val($('#'+$(this).attr('data')+' #td_education_received').text());
            $('input#specialty').val($('#'+$(this).attr('data')+' #td_specialty').text());
            $('input#educational_institution').val($('#'+$(this).attr('data')+' #td_educational_institution').text());
        }
}) ;
}) ;
```

Кнопка отмены которая должна создаваться только один раз при нажатии на кн. редактировать

```
  $(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#clear_fields_education', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('button#education').attr('data-url', 'NewEducation');
        $('button#education').text('<?=$text_add?>');

        $('input#id_education').val('');
        $('input#date_of_the_beginning').val('');
        $('input#end_date').val('');
        $('input#education_received').val('');
        $('input#specialty').val('');
        $('input#educational_institution').val('');

        $('#clear_fields_education').remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете создать глобольную переменную

```
var buttonCteated = false;
```

Затем при создании кнопки проверить

```
if (!buttonCreated) {
  create_button();
  buttonCreated = true;
}
```

Comment: Где создать глобальную переменную? Перед двумя функциями?

Comment: чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос вам нужно понять, что такое глобальная переменная

Answer (score 0):

Поместите элемент

```
<button id="clear_fields_education" class="clear_fields btn btn-default get pull-right" 
  type="button" style="display:none;"></button>
```

в маркап изначально внутри `'#education fieldset legend'` и делайте:

```
$('#clear_fields_education').show();

$('#clear_fields_education').hide();
```

в нужных местах вместо `appendTo` и `remove`.

Или

```
if ($("#clear_fields_education").length == 0) {
  $('<button/>', {
    text: '',
    id: 'clear_fields_education',
    class: 'clear_fields btn btn-default get pull-right'
  }).appendTo('#education fieldset legend');
}
```